# direct link to hidden sheet in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a project management spreadsheet, which has many sheets. in order to keep things tidy, i like to keep them hidden, and show\hide according to my needs usind a script. 
i have a sheet which contains a list of all tasks and a link to their original sheet.

the link leads to the correct URL, but then it changes to that of the last visible sheet.

i've tried using the following function:

```
function onOpen(){
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().showSheet();
}
```

because i thought the hidden sheet is active on document open, but with no luck.

Any ideas?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure I understand exactly what you want to do, but if you want to unhide a sheet and activate it you can do this:

```
function onOpen(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var s = ss.getSheets()[1]
  s.showSheet().activate()
```

}

Comment: my problem is the sheet is hidden, and i want to open it from an external link:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SSIDedit#gid=SheetID

but because it's hidden, the spreadsheet opens with the last visible sheet.